# Bolt cms images aren't displayed

Tags: bolt-cms, imagesource

The images aren't shown (anymore) on my website, which is using Bolt CMS. The connection to the database is just fine, everything is written correctly in the tables. 
When I try to access the systems File Management it gives the error

```
Attempted to call function "exif_read_data" from namespace "PHPExif\Adapter".
```

So my guess is that the actual images are saved in a root folder, but that the link to it from the database is disrupted. 
Everything is still working fine on my local version and I don't remember making any major changes to the config files.

Any ideas on what could cause the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the EXIF extension [installed/enabled in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php)

Comment: Thanks for you response. I'll check when I have access to the files.
Just wondering, if it's indeed the EXIF extension, shouldn't the error also occur on my local version?

Comment: Depends on the PHP set up :-)

Comment: I had to tell my host to change the php to a newer version. Strange because it worked just fine until recently... Thank you!